# jQuery: prevent plugin from re-using the code on exciting elements if extra content is inserted

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, plugins

I hope that the title is clear.

So I have a complex big plugin, which transforms div's into sortable widgets, but I ran into some issue, if somebody ads a new div to the DOM the plugin has to run again to transform the newly added div into a widget, but that this means that it will run it over all already transformed div's. So how can you prevent this. Elements that are wrapped can be checked, so this isn't a big deal, but effects and other things will run several times(depending on how many divs are added to the DOM).

I have made a simple idea how I am using the plugin.(sorry cant post the complete plugin here)

**Not looking for a solution which contains a check on a added class, as this issue is the animations and such(like click events)**

// the divs (the widgets)

```
<div class="widget">
    <div></div>
</div>

<div class="widget">
    <div></div>
</div>

...
...
...
```

// the plugin(basic idea)

```
;(function($, window, document, undefined){

    $.fn.plugin = function(options) { 

        options = $.extend({}, $.fn.plugin.options, options); 

            return this.each(function() {  

                var obj = $(this);

                // for this example we wrap the div
                obj.find(options.widgets).wrap('<div class="wrapped-widget"></div>');

                // add a link to the widget
                options.widgets.prepend('<a href="#" class="link">link</a>')

                // run the animation just once
                options.widgets.on('click', '.link', function(){
                    $(this).next().animate({height: 'toggle'});
                });


            });     
        };


        $.fn.plugin.options = {
            widgets: '.widget',
            // etc          
        };

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

// plugin call

```
$('body').plugin({widgets: '.widget'});
```

// adding new div's to the DOM

```
$('#add').click(function(){
    $('body').append('<div class="widget"><a href="#" class="link">link</a><div></div></div>');
    $('body').plugin({widgets: '.widget'});
});
```

Comment: Couldn't you just filter out elements that currently have a parent with the `wrapped-widget` class? Like this:  `obj.find(options.widgets).not(".wrapped-widget > *").wrap('<div class="wrapped-widget"></div>');`

Comment: yes, I can.....but thats not my issue, the issue is that the plugin will run click events/animation multiple times.

Comment: You're talking about the `$('.link')` code? If so, does that get wrapped as well? If so, you could do a similar filter.

Comment: no if I check for a added class, the animation will still run several times.

Comment: So you're telling me that if you take all `.link` elements, and remove the ones that have an ancestor with the `wrapped-widget` class, they'll still run? I doubt that. But you do need to change your approach for the filter since the `.link` seems to be more deeply nested. `$(".link").not(function() { return $(this).closest(".wrapped-widget").length; }).animate(...`

Comment: The example is just an example, actually I add some button in the div with the plugin, the the on() api, `options.widget.on('click', '.link', function(e){ animation });` but if I add extra widgets to the DOM it will run several times (add 5 divs to the DOM, it will run 5 times)

Comment: In your example, you apply the widget to the page, so you're essentially saying $('body').on('click', '.link') every time you create a widget.

Comment: no I am using options.widgt.on() so no body